# Usage of comma in "Some like it hot, others cold"

Tags: punctuation, commas

How does one punctuate the following construct:

> Some like it hot, others, cold.

Somehow, the two commas seem incorrect or at least awkward. Should the second one be omitted altogether? Or should it be retained while the first one being converted to a semicolon?

Comment: “Some like it hot, others cold.”

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Eva. My confusion was around whether the comma should stay since it's a parenthetical and implies the phrase "like it". The phrase could have been "others like it cold".

Comment: No, the "like it" is implied, the second comma would only be for effect (pause), in which case I would go for an ellipsis, "others ... cold."

Comment: Punctuate it however you like. Just put a comma in when you pause when talking.

Comment: Go with "Some like it hot, others cold." The alternative you suggest ("Some like it hot; others, cold") is over-punctuating. How many punctuation marks does a seven word sentence need? The reader's imagination will supply the tiny pauses that don't rise to the level of a comma.

Comment: @LittleEva Could you please post your comment as an answer so I could accept it and close the thread?

Comment: Why do you think only one should be correct? Have you done any background work to find usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to keep it simple and natural, like speech.

> “Some like it hot, others cold.”

No need to add the words "like it" again, as they are understood in this construction; neither is there a need for the second comma.

Comment: Please use "comments" for suggestions. Incidentally, it happens to be incorrect.

Comment: @Kris - how is it incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

I can see sometimes the more contrasting em-dash at work:

“Some like it hot — others like it cold.”

See 
[I Married a Demon](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hoKDwG3C-f4C&pg=PA19&dq=%22others%20like%20it%20hot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RZMaVairOoaFyQTVpICQCw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22others%20like%20it%20hot%22&f=false) by Beverly Rae

or

“Some like it hot — others, cold.”

Comment: It should be noted that such usage of em-dash is for *emphasising* contrast between two things. Therefore, use it sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

This one is actually quite a difficult one to answer, but it seems more appropriate to use a semicolon where you put your first comma. Alternatively, you could change the statement to "Some like it hot, others like it cold," or "Some like it hot; others like it cold." However, if you require the statement to be "Some like it hot, others cold", then I would suggest replacing your first comma with a semicolon, and place a comma between the words 'others' and 'cold'.

Comment: I'm trying to assess how awkward the 'Some like it hot, others cold.' smooth-flowing version sounds. That's the best way to punctuate this version, in spite of the disguised comma splice; the semicolon _would_ be over the top. However, I'd really prefer a paused version, where I'd use an ellipsis: 'Some like it hot ... others, cold.' Or, in a more formal register, 'Some like it hot; others prefer it cold.'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I covered all this ground with OP earlier in the day, in commentary - except the more formal register. I, finally, settled on, what I felt was the simplest (for me to explain), 'Some like it hot, others cold..'  I only submitted in answer format because OP personally requested. I had been hoping you'd show up. You're very late.

Comment: @Little Eva My ellipsis is different from yours. Smooth flow has only been hinted at, by you and William. The comma splice had _not_ been mentioned. //  And I may be away for some time in the near future. Man shall not live by syntax alone; the great outdoors beckon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - be well

Comment: I like it not too hot; climbing up to Thor's Cave in the Peak District last week was not easy.